# Two Year 2 Edexcel Mechanics A Level questions

Tags: classical-mechanics

Chapter 5 Edexcel Mixed Excercise 5 Question 9 and Challenge Question.

First, question 9 part (a):

[image]

I did $\ F = 700 + 2150 \times9.8\cos10 ^\circ = 4400N \ (2sf)$.

But the answer in the back is $3700N$. They forgot to include the $700N\ $ or I am not understanding something?

$$$$
Secondly, the challenge question:

[image]

I got:

After the cable snaps, the boat decelerates up the slipway for a distance of $\ 2.8m (2sf)\ $ and time $\ 1.1\ $ seconds.

Then assuming that, when the cable snaps the distance from the boat to the water is $\ 8m\ $,  it takes $\ 5.8\ $ seconds for the boat to accelerate back down the slipway until it reaches the water. So total time is $\ 1.1 + 5.8 = 6.9\ $ seconds $\ (2sf)$.

But the answer in the back is $\ 5.8\ $ seconds $\ (2sf).\ $ So again, is this me doing something incorrectly or is it sloppy book answers?

Comment: In the first question your value for the air-resistance would prevent the car from moving (since you're opposing the 700N of engine force as well).  After the air-resistance is taken into account, the car is still moving though.  For the second question, since the boat is being *pulled* up the slipway you should assume that when the cable snaps the boat instantaneously stops and immediately starts descending the slip-way.

Comment: "In the first question your value for the air-resistance would prevent the car from moving (since you're opposing the $700N$ of engine force as well)". No, constant speed (acceleration = $0$) implies the components of the forces in the direction of the slope sum to zero.$$$$
"Since the boat is being pulled up the slipway you should assume that when the cable snaps the boat instantaneously stops and immediately starts descending the slip-way." Really, what's the justification for this?